# Have a file filtered by each column accordingly with a range of values from another columns file

Tags: awk, filter, range, multiple-columns

I would like to have a way to filter one file accordingly to another file, but considering different ranges for each file as the number are different and the names for column 1 are different too. So for example columns 2 and 4 could vary in a range of 50 while columns 3 and 5 for 0.05 and 0.005, respectively.

file 1

```
ddd 10  2   0.3 4   0.02
ccc 250 22  0.2 2   0.04
aaa 10  10  0.10    10  0.02
xxx 12  12  0.12    2   0.01
showman 150 15  0.15    200 0.003
porco   15  100 0.15    15  12
```

file 2

```
super   120 11  0.12    150 0.005
```

output

```
showman 150 15  0.15    200 0.003
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this something that you have to do with many different versions of file 2 and/or will the tolerance range for each column vary?

Comment: If there will be only a few different versions of file 2, I'd suggest writing it directly as an `awk` script that takes `file 1` as input. If there may be many different versions of `file 2`, one way to deal with this would be to write an `awk` script that takes `file 2` as input and generates a script `file2.awk` that does the filtering when supplied with `file 1`.

Comment: I tried some awk command, but the problem is that i don't known how create a variable for each column of one file and use those variables to make a range and search for values in other file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to Simon's solution, but it avoids calling awk twice.

```
function abs(x) {return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)}

BEGIN {
    tol[2]=50
    tol[3]=5
    tol[4]=0.05
    tol[5]=50
    tol[6]=0.005
}

FNR==NR {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
       target[i]=$i
}

FNR < NR {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        if (abs($i - target[i]) > tol[i])
            next
    print
}
```

Call using `awk -f match.awk file2 file1`

Answer (score 1):

The following shell script, which I've called `filterrange`, generates an `awk` script `filterrange.awk` from `file2.txt` and then runs that `awk` script to do the filtering:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'BEGIN { r[2] = 50; r[3] = 5; r[4] = 0.05; r[5] = 50; r[6] = 0.005 }
       { print "function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)}"
         for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
           printf("abs($%s-%s)<=%s", i, $i, r[i])
           if (i < NF) printf(" && ")
           } 
       }' <$1 >filterrange.awk
awk -f filterrange.awk <$2
```

The `abs()` function is from [Absolute value in awk doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184915/absolute-value-in-awk-doesnt-work).

Running this shell script gives the following result:

```
$ filterrange file2.txt file1.txt
showman 150 15  0.15    200 0.003
```

The range tolerances are fixed in the template `awk` script shown here but they could be easily generated from a separate file using a similar approach, if required.

Comment: something is going wrong =\

the only thing that i get is:

`bash filterrange compare.txt permut1.txt 


awk: syntax error at source line 2 source file filterrange.awk
 context is
     abs($2-120)<=50 && abs($3-11)<=5 && abs($4-0.12)<=0,05 &&     abs($5-150)<=50 && >>>  abs($6-0.005)<=0, <<< 
    awk: bailing out at source line 2`

Comment: Your script is work on my friends machine but not on mine while the command of @chthonicdaemon is working on mine and not on his. <o>

Comment: The syntax error results from the sixth column in `file2.txt` being `0,005` (with a comma) when it should be `0.005` (with a period). The answer by @chthonicdaemon is simpler so I'd recommend it over mine but, for some cases, my solution could run faster. I'd have to benchmark to be sure. In any case, it is always best to have a solution that works before going for a solution that is fast.

Comment: I figure out that the problem was that my language options on MAC was changing automatically the output of filterrange.awk for comma. I just have to change the language options of the computer to English and then you command line worked perfectly ;) 
thank you @Simon!