# Shell script for variance percentage calculation

Tags: bash

I need to calculate variance percentage difference between 2 numbers could some one help me how i can do in unix shell scripting. Also the I like to have the output as abs value (always +ve).

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are having with your script? This is not a math problem solving service.

Comment: Value1=3947 Value2=5853, I am calculating variance percentage using  echo "$Value1" "$Value2" | awk '{print ($1-$2)/$1*100}', I like to know its right approach or not..? If its right approach then could you please help me how to get abs value.

Comment: And see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184915/absolute-value-in-awk-doesnt-work) and related answer for the abs function not present in awk

Answer (score 1):

#### Pseudo floating point using *pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)*

I wrote this some years ago:

```
# 
# Bash source file for percent computing
#
# (C) 2011-2012 Felix Hauri - felix@f-hauri.ch
# Licensed under terms of LGPL v3. www.gnu.org

# after sourcing script:
# syntaxe: percent <amount> <total> [varname]

percent() {
    local p=000$((${1}00000/$2))
    printf ${3+-v} $3 "%.2f%%" ${p:0:${#p}-3}.${p:${#p}-3}
}

export -f percent
```

This could be used this way:

```
percent 10 50
20.00%
```

or to set a variable:

```
percent 10 50 result
echo $result
20.00%
```

#### Pseudo *`abs()`* for using wrong negative values

```
percent() {
    local p=000$((${1#-}00000/$2));
    printf ${3+-v} $3 "%.2f%%" ${p:0:${#p}-3}.${p:${#p}-3};
}
```

This will drop any minux sign in your 1st argument:

```
value1=3947
value2=5853
percent $((value1-value2)) $value1 result
echo $result
48.29%
```

Or with more precision:

```
percent() {
    local p;
    printf -v p 00000%u $((${1#-}0000000/$2));
    printf ${3+-v} $3 "%.4f%%" ${p:0:${#p}-5}.${p:${#p}-5};
}
```

Could compute:

```
value1=3947
value2=5853
percent $((value1-value2)) $value1 result
echo $result
48.2898%
```

Of course, as this use bash's 64bits integers, this will only work with *small values*: 1st argument could not be bigger than `922337203685`!