# BASH Arithmetic operation not working

Tags: linux, bash, sh

The code below is meant to calculate the percentage completed when a file is getting dd.

```
percentDone=$(((varFileSize / backupSize) * 100)
```

I am able to debug the script running and the variables get assigned numbers. However as soon as the script runs this line percentDone remains at 0.

I have also tried this:

```
   percentDone=$((varFileSize / backupSize))            
   percentDone=$((percentDone * 100))
```

Any ideas please let me know as really struggling with this problem!
Thank you!!

Comment: How about first multiply, then divide, as is usual with integers

Comment: BASH doesn't support floating point arithmetic. Use `bc -l` or `awk`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Division and Multiplication both have the same dominance. It also wouldn't stop the program from working either.

Anubhava Thank you, I will look into this!

Comment: That's why the order matters. What is 1 / 100 * 100 and what is 1 * 100 / 100 when done with integers? That's the problem.

Comment: @anubhava: Have a look on this [Pseudo floating point using pure bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33033053/1765658)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since bash only supports integers you have to do the calculation other way around:

```
percentDone=$((varFileSize * 100 / backupSize))
```

Otherwise dividing anything less than `backupSize` with it will result in zero and multiplying it with anything won't help.