# How to obtain the difference between 2 columns with awk in a tsv

Tags: awk, sum, multiple-columns

I have a kind of the following tsv file:

```
Hi 10 6
hello 7 1
Hi 6 2
```

Hence, the related output should be:

```
Hi 10 6 4
hello 7 1 6
Hi 6 2 4
```

I'd like to create a 4th column with the difference between the 2 columns $2 and $3, but in an absolute value.

I am trying with the following line, but with no right result:

```
awk -F\t '{print $0 OFS $2-$3}' file
```

How can I do?
Marco

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute value in awk doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184915/absolute-value-in-awk-doesnt-work); see the various answers for a few ideas on how to implement `abs()` functionality

Comment: Please provide desired output

Answer (score 1):

When you write `-F\t` without quotes you're inviting the shell to interpret the string and so the shell will read the backslash and leave you with `-Ft`. In **some** awks `-Ft` means "use a tab as the separator" while in others it means "use the character `t` as the separator". I assume since you say your file is a TSV that you want it to use tabs so just write your code to not invite the shell to interpret it, i.e. `-F'\t'` instead of `-F\t`.

After that to get the absolute value is obvious and well-covered in many postings:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, ($2>$3 ? $2-$3 : $3-$2)}' file
Hi  10  6   4
hello   7   1   6
Hi  6   2   4
```

I changed from using `-F'\t'` to `FS="\t"` because both FS and OFS need to be set to `"\t"` and so setting them both together to the same character instead of separately avoids duplication.